# Jest fails with error: Cannot find module 'react/lib/ReactComponentTreeHook'

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have installed Jest v17.0.3 in my react project.

When I run jest locally it works fine, but on the build server it fails with:

> Error: Cannot find module 'react/lib/ReactComponentTreeHook' from 'ReactDebugTool.js'

Both machines are running node version 6.9.1 and npm version 4.0.2.

Comment: I had a similar problem today, I think it has to do with missing dependencies because It happened for me in the context of changing my `package.json` file.

Comment: I had accidentally removed `npm install` from my build script, and because of that I had old modules.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

use same version of react and react-dom. My problem fixed after using this command

```
npm install --save react@15.4.0 react-dom@15.4.0
```

this problem specially occurs on react 15.4.0 above.

Comment: In my case it was `react-test-renderer` that was not up to par with react and react-dom.

Answer (score 5):

Can you check which version of React you are using? Is it the same on both servers? I would try removing `node_modules` and reinstalling the dependencies. The reason I am suggesting this is that in React v15.4.0 you cannot import private apis and it seems that `ReactDebugTools.js` is trying to import from `react/lib/...`.

From the blogpost about React v15.4.0 ([Link](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/11/16/react-v15.4.0.html)):

> However, there is a possibility that you imported private APIs from react/lib/*, or that a package you rely on might use them. We would like to remind you that this was never supported, and that your apps should not rely on internal APIs. The React internals will keep changing as we work to make React better.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

In the latest versions of react we often see this error as we have loaded 2 versions of react:

To make sure you have just 1 version, run the following in your terminal:

1. npm ls react-dom
   [image]
2. npm ls react
   [image]

Both the react and react-dom versions need to be same. 
If any one of these returns more than 1 version then that's not supported. You have to then correct it in your corresponding package.json

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and i removed the node_modules and ran npm install and it fixed the problem.

Comment: While answers are always appreciated, this question was asked 2 months ago, and already had an accepted solution. The accepted solution also covers the **exact** point that you raised. Please try to avoid 'bumping' questions to the top by providing answers to them, unless the question was not already marked as resolved, or you found a dramatically better alternative approach to the problem :)