# React Native Unit Testing (Jest)

Tags: unit-testing, react-native, jestjs

I'm a student, who new to jest unit testing, I found some tutorials related to the Jest and I have written some sample code to learn this. But unfortunately it did not work. I have tried several hours to solve this problem, but couldn't find a way.

Here is my code.

**This is my App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Alert, Button, TextInput, View, Text, StyleSheet, KeyboardAvoidingView, TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native'

export default class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      username: '',
      password: '',
    };
  }

  onLogin() {
    const { username, password } = this.state;

    Alert.alert('Credentials', `${username} + ${password}`);

  }

  render() {

    return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container}>

        <TextInput 
          value={this.state.username}
          onChangeText={(username) => this.setState({ username })}
          placeholder={'Username'}
          returnKeyType = "next"
          keyboardType = "email-address"
          autoCapitalize = "none"
          autoCorrect = {false}
          onSubmitEditing = {()=> this.passwordInput.focus()}
          style={styles.input}/>

        <TextInput
          value={this.state.password}
          onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({ password })}
          placeholder={'Password'}
          secureTextEntry={true}
          returnKeyType = "go"
          style={styles.input}
          ref = {(input) => this.passwordInput = input}/>

        {/* <Button
          title={'Login'}
          style={styles.input}
          onPress={this.onLogin.bind(this)}/> */}

          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={this.onLogin.bind(this)}>
            <Text>Login</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
  input: {
    width: '90%',
    height: 44,
    padding: 10,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'black',
    marginBottom: 10,
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight: 10,
  },

  button: {
    width: '90%',
    height: 44,
    padding: 10,
    borderWidth: 0,
    alignItems: 'center',
    color: '#F5FCFF',
    marginBottom: 10,
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight: 10,
  },

});
```

**This is App.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Login from './App';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

describe('Login', function () {
  let component;
  let textInput;
  const defaultState = {text: ''};

  beforeEach(function () {
    component = shallow(<Login />);
    textInput = component.find('TextInput');
  });

  it('has default state', function () {
    expect(component.state()).to.eql(defaultState);
  });

  it('renders input field with placeholder', function () {
    const expectedPlaceholder = 'Username';
    expect(textInput).to.have.length(1);
    expect(textInput.props().placeholder).to.eql(expectedPlaceholder);
  });

});
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "AwsomProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.55.4",
    "yarn-install": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-jest": "23.0.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^4.0.0",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-15": "^1.0.5",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "jest": "^23.1.0",
    "mocha": "^5.2.0",
    "react-native-mock": "^0.3.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Thank you..

Comment: What is the error? share your package.json file also.

Comment: Shared it.. Thank you.

Comment: what about the error ?

Comment: It says this "Test suite failed to run : 

  Cannot find module 'react/lib/ReactComponentTreeHook' from 'ReactDebugTool.js'

      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:210:17)  "

Comment: can you check the solutions mentioned here ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40911760/jest-fails-with-error-cannot-find-module-react-lib-reactcomponenttreehook

Comment: Thank you sir. that error is gone. But it shows this,                               
                                                                                                             
 Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

      25 |   it('renders input field with placeholder', function () {
      26 |     const expectedPlaceholder = 'Username';
    > 27 |     expect(textInput.props().placeholder).to.eql(expectedPlaceholder);
         |            ^
      28 |   });

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, I import npm install chai & add import { expect } from 'chai'; to the project. It worked. Thanks again.

Comment: Happy to know that it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Test suite failed to run : Cannot find module 'react/lib/ReactComponentTreeHook error, use the same version of react and react-dom. Ref more details here : [Jest fails with error: Cannot find module 'react/lib/ReactComponentTreeHook'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40911760/jest-fails-with-error-cannot-find-module-react-lib-reactcomponenttreehook)